# yii2 (hide header and left menu using adminLte)

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUsWf.jpg)

Hello all, i want to ask how to hide header and left menu in my sign up form. i use adminLte. when i open sign in, header and left menu didn't show. but, when i go to sign up form, header and left menu shown. please help me guys. here is my code in main.php

```
enter code here
```

if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'login') {

```
echo $this->render(
    'main-login',
    ['content' => $content]
);
```

} else {

```
if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'register') {
    backend\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
} else {
    backend\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
}
dmstr\web\AdminLteAsset::register($this);

$directoryAsset = Yii::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl('@vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/dist');
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<!-- <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini"> -->
<body class="<?= AdminLteHelper::skinClass() ?> fixed">
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<div class="wrapper">

    <?= $this->render(
        'header.php',
        ['directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
    ) ?>

    <?= $this->render(
        'left.php',
        ['directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
    )
    ?>

    <?= $this->render(
        'content.php',
        ['content' => $content, 'directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
    ) ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you only add condition for login action.
So it load main-login.php content only.
You have add another condition then rendor your page.

I think below changes would be help full for you

```
  <?php
        use yii\helpers\Html;

        /* @var $this \yii\web\View */
        /* @var $content string */


        if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'login') { 
            echo $this->render(
                'main-login',
                ['content' => $content]
            );
        }    
   else if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'sign-in') { 
                echo $this->render(
                    'main-login',
                    ['content' => $content]
                );
            }
   else {

            if (class_exists('backend\assets\AppAsset')) {
                backend\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
            } else {
                app\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
            }

            dmstr\web\AdminLteAsset::register($this);

            $directoryAsset = Yii::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl('@vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/dist');
            ?>
            <?php $this->beginPage() ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
            <head>
                <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>"/>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
                <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
                <?php $this->head() ?>
            </head>
            <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
            <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
            <div class="wrapper">

                <?= $this->render(
                    'header.php',
                    ['directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
                ) ?>

                <?= $this->render(
                    'left.php',
                    ['directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
                )
                ?>

                <?= $this->render(
                    'content.php',
                    ['content' => $content, 'directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
                ) ?>

            </div>

            <?php $this->endBody() ?>
            </body>
            </html>
            <?php $this->endPage() ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

So the above else if condition will only load the main-login with the content which is render by the action sign-in.